# Hangman help, trying to see if user input has already been used

Tags: java, input

I am building a hangman game but I need help trying to check whether the user input was used before (like they guess `a` then `b` and than `a` again):

```
String input = console.next();
        if(input.length()>1){
            System.out.println("One letter at a time");
        }
        //to insert data into arrays
        letter[a]=input;
    if (!input.equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
      System.out.println("You have aready enter " + input);
    } else {
      continue;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us more code than the snippet above?

Comment: String input = console.next();
  if(input.length()>1){
   System.out.println("One letter at a time");
  }
  //to insert data into arrays
  letter[a]=input;

Comment: im thinking of making the input to an array

Comment: Umm... that looks like C++ syntax. Are you quite sure you're working on a Javascript project?

Comment: yea im woking on javascrip project im in high school and taking java and thats what i was thought

Comment: Java and Javascript are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This will add the method you want to use to the `String` class:

```
String.prototype.equalsIgnoreCase = function(other_string) {
    return this.toLowerCase() === other_string.toLowerCase();
}
```

Make sure you're not trying to compare a `String` to itself, though, like you're doing with `input` in your question. Also, use JavaScript syntax for web-served files instead of C++ syntax.

Comment: thank you ill tryin inputting the method and i didnt know i was making C++ syntax is suppose to be java, and where is says other_string will input go there

Comment: is java , isnt javascrip for like websites and stuff like that

Comment: JavaScript is included in or with web pages and is interpreted by web browsers. You tagged your post with JavaScript.